# Is the operation associative

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, associativity

Is it known that the multiplication of matrices is a associative operation ?

So,is the relation $(A \cdot B) \cdot C=A \cdot (B \cdot C)$ true??

($A,B,C$ are matrices)

Comment: Why boolean algebra tag?? Multiplication of matrices is a monoid operation (associative, with identity).

Comment: I changed it.....!So,is the relation true?

Comment: Yes! Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_the_matrix_product_.28any_number.29 Is it what you mean?

Comment: Yeah.... It is.

Comment: Once you realize that matrices are linear functions and multiplication of matrices is function composition, it becomes clear that it is associative.

Comment: I understand..thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a well known fact which is proved in any (descent) linear algebra book.

The proof is simple, just calculate both the RHS and the LHS to see both are the same

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much!!!